# How do I get the screen width and height when initializing an Android Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, screen, live-wallpaper

Trying to code a simple Live wallpaper for android. I'm having trouble finding out how to capture the screen size at initialization.

Any thoughts on how I might can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onSurfaceChanged` provides **width** and **height** as part of its parameters.  When this method is called during initialization you can grab the values and save them to method variables like **mWidth** and **mHeight**.  Then you'll have them anywhere, at anytime to use in your code.

Make note that this method is called **AFTER** `onCreate` and `onSurfaceCreated`, so anything that needs width and/or height will have to wait until `onSurfaceChanged` gets fired.

Check this sample by Google for a clearer picture:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/src/com/example/android/livecubes/cube1/CubeWallpaper1.html

Answer (score 1):

Does android.util.DisplayMetrics help?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html